# How to serve the results of analyses in R on a Web page?

Tags: python, r, web, statistics, analysis

**Context:**

In a machine learning / data analysis project, I'd like to be able to perform analyses and publish their results on a Web page.  I have looked around and R seems to be the best option for performing the analyses.

**Question:**

How does one make the results available through a Web page?

**Additional considerations:**

- Integration with Python or other systems is a viable option.
- Bonus points if it is possible to run the analyses and display the results interactively.

Comment: Have a look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/ and http://ggvis.rstudio.com/

Comment: I would look into IPython

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways, two of which are:

1. Link between the language the web layer is programmed in and R, such as [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) for python that allow the web layer to call R.
2. Connect to an R server.  Python can connect to [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) through [pyRserve](https://github.com/ralhei/pyRserve).

Which one is best depends on the nature of your web application.

Comment: Thanks!  Any ideas on how rich the `rpy2` interface is?  How does it work for plots (can I somehow export / import the graphs?).